# How to read data from an excel file with header in java/spring

Tags: java, excel, spring, import, apache-poi

[image: Excel file]

I have this excel file. How to create a request in java/spring to read data from that file?

The problem i encounter is with the first two rows. I cant fetch data from excel for those. I don't know how to do this in apache POI.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was this:

```
String supplierName = null;

    // GET Supplier name
    for (int r = 0; r <= rows; r++) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
        if (r == 2) {
            break;
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            if (r == 1) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c);
                supplierName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with Apache POI.

```java
try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent))) {
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
    String value = cell.getStringValue();
    ...
}
```

This should be enough to help you to start coding.